# struts tag lib is preventing positioning a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, struts2

I'm trying to do in my real code what I've done with JSFiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/tekknow/8qj99bkt/13/
I want the div to animate in from the right.  Because the css is set to inline-block, it should appear immediately after the text field.  But unfortunately, my real code uses a struts tag lib which interferes with this behavior.  Looking at the page source I can see struts places the label and password fields inside a table.  Hence the div ends up between two tr blocks resulting in the div appearing above the form instead of to the right.

**HTML**

```
 <s:password label="New Password" name="NewPwd" class="infoReset" id="pwd"/>
    <div id="rules">
        1 upper case letter<br>
        1 lower case letter<br>
        1 special char among !@#$%^&*_=+-/<br>
        8 char length
    </div>
```

What struts does to it:

```
    <tr>
    <td class="tdLabel"><label for="pwd" class="label">New Password:</label></td>
    <td><input type="password" name="NewPwd" id="pwd" /></td>
    </tr>

    <div id="rules">
        1 upper case letter<br>
        1 lower case letter<br>
        1 special char among !@#$%^&*_=+-/<br>
        8 char length
    </div>
    <tr>
```

Even positioning the div with js fails to have any affect

**Javascript**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#pwd').focus(function() {
            $('#rules').css({left: '870px', top: '280px'});
            $('#rules').show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 500);
        });
```

**CSS**

```
#rules { 
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    width: 260px;
    position: 'fixed';
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888888;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

I've tried position absolute, relative, and fixed.  No difference.  Any suggestions?

Comment: place `div` right after the input

Comment: There is no input in the original html.  It only appears because struts generates it.

Comment: Original is not html